# Conditionally hide checkout field on chosen payment method at checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am using the following code for hiding credit card number field for chosen payment method. It's hiding the field perfectly but when the field is hidden and I click on Place Order button, it still shows 'Credit  Card Number is required'.

```
// show hide credit card fields start
   add_action( 'wp_footer', 'conditionally_show_hide_card_number_field' );
   function conditionally_show_hide_card_number_field(){
// Only on checkout page
 if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
?>
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        var a = 'input[name="payment_method"]',
            b = a + ':checked',
            c = '#credit_card_number_field'; // The checkout field <p> container selector

        // Function that shows or hide checkout fields
        function showHide( selector = '', action = 'show' )
        {
            if( action == 'show' )
                $(selector).show( 200, function(){
                    $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                });
            else
                $(selector).hide( 200, function(){
                    $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                });
            $(selector).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
            $(selector).removeClass("woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field");
        }

        // Initialising: Hide if choosen payment method is "credit_card"
        if( $(b).val() == 'elavon_converge_credit_card' )
            showHide( c, 'hide' );
        else
            showHide( c );

        // Live event (When payment method is changed): Show or Hide based on "credit_card"
        $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', a, function() {
            if( $(b).val() == 'elavon_converge_credit_card' )
                showHide( c, 'hide' );
            else
                showHide( c );
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
endif;
}
// show hide credit card fields ends
```

Please suggest the change in code how can I overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overcome this unless you make the CC number field optional which is a bad idea because then you're agreeing to accept CC payments without a CC number, too; and those payments will fail.  This becomes a usability nightmare.  WooCommerce, by default, has it's own way of handling this and no manual effort is needed by you (entire section is hidden and non-mandatory when choosing another payment method). What have you changed, or what are you trying to accomplish which has removed this built-in feature?  I'm thinking that you might just be asking the wrong question.